# how to set the length of excerpt in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I display my excerpt with

```
<?php echo get_the_excerpt ?>
```

I want to set a custom  length for excerpt with a hook.

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 10;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 10 );
```

The problem is that this doesn't work. I don't know why.

Who knows a hook for setting the length of excerpt in my case?

Comment: also - in your `echo get_the_excerpt` you are missing `()` here

Answer (score 2):

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Way 2 :

```
<?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,30); ?>
```

**Existing code update :**

```
 <?php $args = array( 'numberposts' => 1, 'post_type' => 'aaaa', ); 
 $result = wp_get_recent_posts($args); 

 foreach( $result as $p ) : ?>
  <h2><?php echo $p['post_title'] ?></a></h2> 
  <p><?php echo wp_trim_words($p['post_excerpt'], 30); ?></p>

  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: it is the same function as yours - just added priority

Comment: @Stender Some time priority cause an issue. I have added alternative solution as well.

Comment: it can, but in that case, i would use `preg_match` and regex, to make sure, that it ends on a whole word.

Comment: something like `$shortenedExcerpt = substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0, 30);
   $newExcerpt = substr($shortenedExcerpt, 0, strrpos($shortenedExcerpt, ' '));`  could maybe also work.

Comment: @ Vasim Shaikh  i have the same code ... <?php
     $args = array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
     'post_type' => 'aaaa',
      );
      $result = wp_get_recent_posts($args);
      foreach( $result as $p ) : ?>
      <h2><?php echo $p['post_title'] ?></a></h2>
       <p><?php echo $p['post_excerpt'] ?></p>
       <?php
      endforeach;
      ?> ... how here i can set the length of  post_excerpt?

Comment: @ Stender @ Vasim Shaikh <p><?php echo  substr($p['post_excerpt'], 0, 30); ?></p>    set the length of letters, but what will be the sintax for words length?

Comment: i solved with        <p><?php echo wp_trim_words($p['post_excerpt'], 30); ?></p>

Answer (score 0):

set the length of excerpt in Wordpress

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Answer (score 0):

add the below line to your `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', function($length) {return 20;}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

- edit the “20” to the number of words you want to show in your excerpts.